# How to show only some data in select?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models:

```
class ArticleTemplate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.TexField()
    [...]
    owner = models.ForeignKey(user)

class Article(models.Model):
    template = models.ForeignKey(ArticleTemplate)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.TexField()
    [...]
    owner = models.ForeignKey(user)
```

And form for Article:

```
class ArticleForm(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'template', 'title', 'text')
```

But select shows me all templates, also those are not owned by the request.user.

How to shows only data assigned to logged user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter foreign key select in Django ModelForm by call queryset in your view:

```
form.template.queryset = ArticleTemplate.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `__init__` method to ArticleForm:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    logged_user = kwargs.pop("logged_user")
    super(ArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    templates = logged_user.article_template_set.all()
    self.fields['template'].queryset = templates
```

From view:

```
form = ArticleForm(logged_user=request.user) #GET request

form = ArticleForm(request.POST, logged_user=request.user) #POST
```